# Magento CMS Block Collection, can't filter by store id - addStoreFilter([storeid]) not working

Tags: php, collections, magento

How to filter a cms/block (static block) collection ?

This works for cms page:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('cms/page');
$collection = $model->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(3);
```

This does NOT work (returns unfiltered collection):

```
$model = Mage::getModel('cms/block');
$collection = $model->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(3);
```

I also tried working with the resource models 'cms/block' and 'cms/block_collection', no results.

Why is Magento that inconsequent ?! Sometimes I really start hating Magento for this.
Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you exactly mean with unfiltered?

The addStoreFilter has a 2nd parameter to include the admin store as well

```
addStoreFilter($store, $withAdmin = true)
```

So if you have any static blocks linked to all stores, these will also be in your collection.

Is this the issue you have?

Comment: this could be the problem, yes.

Comment: when i try it with addStoreFilter(3, false) i get no blocks. but there are blocks related to store "3" for sure.

Comment: Does the table `cms_block_store` also reflect that?

Comment: sorry, I had another dumb problem in my code, your solution was fine

Comment: If I try this `$cms_blocks = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('identifier', array('eq' => 'block_slide1'))->addStoreFilter($storeId, false)` and print the query, I have:

`SELECT 'main_table'.* FROM 'cms_block' AS 'main_table' WHERE ('identifier' = 'block_slide1')`

It doesn't add store filter. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection();
$select = $collection->getSelect()->join(
    array('block_store' => $collection->getTable('cms/block_store')),
    'main_table.block_id = block_store.block_id',
    array('store_id')
)->where('block_store.store_id IN (?)', array(8));
foreach ($collection as $block) {
   // here you can use $block 
}
```

You can do the same for `cms/page`. Just change

`cms/block` -> `cms/page` and `cms/block_store` -> `cms/page_store`

Comment: but this does not return a collection of blocks. how to go on ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all thanks to Mike and oleksii.scarychevskyi.
Both answers helped me to get it working.
Using this works perfectly and i prefer this one:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(3, false);
```

oleksiis solution did also work, I didn't know we can change the select in that way.

Comment: What version were you using?

I don't understand my issue (I'm using 1.9.2.4 version); if I print the query of collection loaded (`$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(3, false);`), I obtain this log: `SELECT 'main_table'.* FROM 'cms_block' AS 'main_table'` **without store filter**.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to get static block by identifier:

```
$storeId = 2;
$content = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId($storeId)->load('aboutus')->getContent();
echo  $content;
```